# The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception error using mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I got the Below error 
The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

and my app.config file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="CTX" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=test_db_test;Uid=root;Pwd=root;" />
</connectionStrings>
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
<parameters>
<parameter value="v11.0" />
</parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
</provider>
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
<remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data></configuration>
```

I cant figure out whats wrong ?? help on this

Comment: Look at the full exception stack trace - it will have a nested exception inside the `TypeInitializationException`, and that will give details of what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks I looked full exception stack trace there was a solution for this, the config section should be first child